# Phonegap taps not registering until next tap on iPad

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, iscroll4

I've been testing a cordova app on my iPad and I'm encountering an issue where taps are sometimes not registered or take a long time to register, but if I tap some other region of the screen while I'm waiting both taps immediately register. The taps occur within an iscroll view and I'm using jQuery Mobile vmouse events to listen for them.
One experiment I've done is to use setInterval to periodically move a UI element, and I've found that when the taps are not registering the UI element stops moving. I haven't yet determined whether the lockup is happening in the Javascript or only in the DOM rendering layer.

I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue and if there are any tricks I can use to avoid it. Since tapping the screen again seems to stop the lockup I'm wondering if I could somehow simulate periodic taps. However, triggering "tap" events on the document doesn't seem to be sufficient for that. As a last resort I'm planning to put an animated webview avatar in the corner of the screen with the caption "Hi, I'm your device's webview. I try really hard to make web-apps work but sometimes I get stuck. If I stop moving just give me a tap on the shoulder and I'll continue humming along."

Comment: Try `vclick` instead of `tap`.

Comment: @Omar how can I chat with you ? :D sometimes I feel guilty I answer questions instead of just leaving comments like you :)

Comment: @abdu http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33684/room-for-omar-and-abdu

Comment: I tried switching all my taps to vclicks and it seemed to have no effect.

Comment: I am also using iscroll, and oddly enough, binding to tap instead of click worked perfectly fine for me.  \*shrug\*

Answer (score 1):

I found a hack that seems to prevent the tap delays. I have no clue why it works, I stumbled upon it completely by accident. All that it involves is calling the jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut functions on some element after the tap event.

```
  var $refresher = $('<div>');
  $.mobile.pageContainer.append($refresher);
  $refresher.fadeIn().fadeOut();
```

It would still be nice to have an answer that explains what might actually be going on.